# Is it possible to change dynalite settings when using jest-dynalite

Tags: jestjs, dynalite, jest-dynalite

My jest tests are very slow at the moment and I suspect that one of the reasons is that dynality has slow defaults, such as an intentional delay on all updates.  Is it possible to change these settings in a jest-dynalite environment?

My `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  "preset": 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
   ...
  "testEnvironment": "jest-dynalite/environment.js"
};
```

I tried exploring the `import * as dynalite from 'jest-dynalite';` object but did not get far.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is already done, can be seen [here](https://github.com/freshollie/jest-dynalite/blob/master/src/db.ts):

```
export const dynaliteInstance = dynalite({
  createTableMs: 0,
  deleteTableMs: 0,
  updateTableMs: 0,
});
```